# Webpack doesn't recompile / reload after adding Flowtype loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, flowtype

I have the following webpack configuration and after adding the flowtype-loader, webpack doesn't recompile on file save. Any ideas what I can try? It works perfectly without the loader.

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import FlowtypePlugin from 'flowtype-loader/plugin';

export default {
    entry:{
        app: [
            './src/application.js',
            './ui-kit/src/scss/main.scss'
        ],
        vendor: [
            'jed',
            'decentstringformatter'
        ]
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'application.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js(x?)$/, loader: "flowtype", exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js(x?)$/,
                loaders: [
                    "babel-loader?{presets:[['es2015',{modules:false}],'stage-0','react']}"
                ],
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!autoprefixer?{browsers:["last 10 versions", "Chrome >= 4","Firefox >= 2", "Explorer >= 8"]}!sass')
            }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('application.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js'),
        new FlowtypePlugin()
    ]
};
```

Here are the webpack-dev-server options

```
var myConfig = Object.assign(webpackOptions);
    myConfig.devtool = 'eval';
    myConfig.debug = true;
    myConfig.entry.app.unshift('webpack-dev-server/client?'+ devEnvEndpoint);
    myConfig.entry.app.unshift('webpack/hot/dev-server');
    var compiler = webpack(myConfig);
    var devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
        publicPath: myConfig.output.publicPath,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        contentBase: devEnvHost,
        stats: {
            colors: true
        },
        proxy: {
            '**' : {
                target: devEnvHost,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I solved this [by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-typecheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-typecheck) instead of the loader

here's my .babelrc and it works perfectly, recompiles and checks the types as well.

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["typecheck", "react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```